# Reduce object by date

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've got an array like this:

```
transactionData = [
  { MaterialID: "3000745",
    TransactionQuantity: "2.000",
    TransactionDate: "01/15/2020"
  },
  { MaterialID: "3000745",
    TransactionQuantity: "3.000",
    TransactionDate: "2/24/2020"
  },
  { MaterialID: "3000051",
    TransactionQuantity: "1.000",
    TransactionDate: "3/10/2020"
  },
  { MaterialID: "3000051",
    TransactionQuantity: "1.000",
    TransactionDate: "4/01/2020"
  }
]
```

And an object like this:

```
dateObj = {
  "Jan-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
  "Feb-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
  "Mar-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
  "Apr-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 }
}
```

I'm trying to reduce transactionData and return an object like this:

```
{
  "3000051": {
      "monthlyVolume": {
          "Jan-20": {
            "sum": 0,
            "count": 0
          },
          "Feb-20": {
            "sum": 0,
            "count": 0
          },
          "Mar-20": {
            "sum": 1,
            "count": 1
          },
          "Apr-20": {
            "sum": 1,
            "count": 1
          }
      }
  },
  "3000745": {
      "monthlyVolume": {
        "Jan-20": {
            "sum": 2,
            "count": 1
        },
        "Feb-20": {
            "sum": 3,
            "count": 1
        },
        "Mar-20": {
            "sum": 0,
            "count": 0
        },
        "Apr-20": {
            "sum": 0,
            "count": 0
        }
      }
   }
}
```

For some reason, my reduce function is returning the same values for both MaterialIDs. I've been working on this for a couple of hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any help from the SO community.

Below is my code (note, I'm using dayjs to format).

```
 let result = transactionData.reduce((acc, {
    MaterialID, TransactionDate, TransactionQuantity }) => {
    let date = dayjs(TransactionDate).format("MMM-YY");

  const _material = (acc[MaterialID] ?? = { monthlyVolume: dateObj });

  _material.monthlyVolume[date].sum += parseFloat(TransactionQuantity);
  _material.monthlyVolume[date].count++;

    return acc;
  }, {}
)
```

Here's a codepen with my attempt as well.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/twill3/pen/zYwPRWr?editors=0011)

Comment: Can you explain why your expected output is as such?

Comment: The expected output is not right, I mean `3000051` has `TransactionDate` of only `Mar` and `Apr` and you want that in `Jan` and `Feb`

Comment: I inadvertently had the values transposed, they're now corrected. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You have used

```
const _material = (acc[MaterialID] ?? = { monthlyVolume: dateObj });
```

which is syntactically Incorrect because of space in between `?? =`

**2)** You have to clone the `dateObj` to create 2 separate object for each `MaterialID`

```
function createDateObjClone(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = { ...obj[curr] };
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

and use it as

```
monthlyVolume: { ...createDateObjClone(dateObj) }
```

[YOUR NEW RUNNING CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/eYWeMEW?editors=0012)

You can also try my solution

```js
const transactionData = [
  {
    MaterialID: "3000745",
    TransactionQuantity: "2.000",
    TransactionDate: "01/15/2020",
  },
  {
    MaterialID: "3000745",
    TransactionQuantity: "3.000",
    TransactionDate: "2/24/2020",
  },
  {
    MaterialID: "3000051",
    TransactionQuantity: "1.000",
    TransactionDate: "3/10/2020",
  },
  {
    MaterialID: "3000051",
    TransactionQuantity: "1.000",
    TransactionDate: "4/01/2020",
  },
];

const dateDict = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
];

const dateObj = {
  "Jan-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
  "Feb-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
  "Mar-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
  "Apr-20": { sum: 0, count: 0 },
};

const getMonthObj = (acc, MaterialID, { month, year }) => acc[MaterialID]["monthlyVolume"][`${dateDict[month - 1]}-${year.slice(-2)}`];

function createDateObjClone(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = { ...obj[curr] };
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function addData(target, sum) {
  target.sum = +sum;
  target.count++;
}

const result = transactionData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { MaterialID, TransactionQuantity, TransactionDate } = curr;
  const [month, , year] = TransactionDate.split("/");

  if (!acc[MaterialID])
    acc[MaterialID] = { monthlyVolume: { ...createDateObjClone(dateObj) } };

  const obj = getMonthObj(acc, MaterialID, { month, year });
  if (obj) addData(obj, TransactionQuantity);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is here:

```
_material = (acc[MaterialID] ?? = { monthlyVolume: dateObj }
```

let's clean it up a bit:

```
_material = { monthlyVolume: dateObj }
```

This will have all the `monthlyVolume` properties reference the exact same thing as `DataObj`, namely the unnamed object you got from your database to begin with. But of course, anyone holding a reference to it will be free to modify it, so you'll end up cumulating all the sums supposedly performed on different items into this single, common recipient. Printing your sales record will simply display the same sub-object twice.

Adding a `const` qualifier to `_material` doesn't change a thing. It has no effect on the object referenced by that identifier.

A minimalistic reproduction of our problem:

```
var DataObj = { surprise: 123 } // DataObj references a freshly created object
var record1 = { data: DataObj } // record1 is a freshly created object too, *but*
                                // "record1.data" references the same
                                // object as our old DataObj buddy
var record2 = { data: DataObj } // same thing for any number of similar references

record1.data.surprise+= 456; // anyone referencing the underlying object
console.log(DataObj);        // is free to change its value, which will be
console.log (record1.data);  // reflected in every identifier that can access it
console.log (record2.data);

>>> Object { surprise: 579 }
>>> Object { surprise: 579 }
>>> Object { surprise: 579 }
```

Now watch this bit of deep magic:

```
var Phoney_Identity = obj => ({ ...obj }) // a cryptic way of shallow-copying an object
var DataObj = { surprise: 123 } // DataObj is a freshly created object
var a_buddy_of_DataObj = Phoney_Identity (DataObj) // its buddy is a shallow copy
DataObj.surprise = 42 // which is enough to decorrelate them
console.log (DataObj) // as long as they don't contain arrays or objects
console.log (a_buddy_of_DataObj)

>>> Object { surprise: 42 }
>>> Object { surprise: 123 }
```

If the object contains arrays or sub-objects you'll have to redo the same trick recursively to get a true deep copy. Hence the "phoney" in the name.

Most of the pseudo-functional snippets that get copied around happen to work because most objects are either never modified or created from scratch (by horrible, impure code!). Also, the sacrosanct `map`, `filter`, `reduce` trilogy all return shallow copies of their arguments, which further helps avoiding the same pitfall when only slight modifications are made. But the whole thing is likely to blow up in your face soon as you start tinkering with slightly more complicated data structures.

Without a helper library, trying to play the functional programming game is asking for serious trouble. Besides, the obfuscation of lambda functions, spread operators and destructuring is a perfect hiding place for these nasty little bugs.